# SQL Server 2008 find the prior to last timestamp record

Tags: sql-server, timestamp

I am trying to query a table in order to find the prior to last record. For the moment i have tried various solution such as this code but i cannnot make it work (see below)

the fields i am trying to query are from this table `[CMI_Industry_Workload].[dbo].[Gantt_Value]` and are `[ProjectName]` and `[TimeStamp]`.

The first field is a string field and the second one is a timestamp field.

```
select t.*
from  (Select t.*
              row_number() over (partition by [ProjectName] order by [Timestamp]) as seqnum,
              count(*) over (partition by [ProjectName]) as cnt
       from [CMI_Industry_Workload].[dbo].[Gantt_Value] t
      ) t
where seqnum in (1, cnt - 1, cnt);
```

So i expect to have not the most recent record but the one before that.

Thanks a lot

Gary

Comment: SQL Server 2008 <> MySQL Server 2008. Infact there is no such thing as MySQL Server 2008. Moreover, your query is definitely from SQL Server.

Comment: yes indeed, sorry i mixed up

Comment: By "prior to last record" do you mean the penultimate? If so, the Penultimate row in Ascending Order, is the **2nd** row in Descending. It seems you know how to use `ROW_NUMBER` so you should be able to work out what you need there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should find prior to last record in your table (assuming that data is sorted by `Timestamp` field. This will sort rows in descending order by `Timestamp`, skip (offset) 1 (very last) row and fetch only one row, making that prior to last one.

```sql
SELECT T.*
FROM [CMI_Industry_Workload].[dbo].[Gantt_Value] AS T
ORDER BY [Timestamp] DESC
OFFSET 1 ROWS
FETCH NEXT 1 ROWS ONLY;
```

Above will work with 2012+

This is version with `ROW_NUMBER`

```sql
SELECT *
FROM (  SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY [Timestamp] DESC) AS Seq
        FROM [CMI_Industry_Workload].[dbo].[Gantt_Value]) AS T
WHERE T.Seq = 2;
```

This will order yet again by `Timestamp` desc and will pick 2nd value (prior to last one).

Keep in mind that MSSQL 2008 is (or soon will be) out of support. I'd strongly encourage upgrading.

#### Update

Based on OP's comment, this must be the answer then:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM (  SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY [ProjectName] ORDER BY [Timestamp] DESC) AS Seq
        FROM [CMI_Industry_Workload].[dbo].[Gantt_Value]) AS T
WHERE T.Seq > 1;
```

#### Second update

If `Timestamp` values happen to be duplicates and you want to treat them as *same*, you might want to use `DENSE_RANK()` instead of `ROW_NUMBER()`. It's going to assign same sequence number if current value matches previous value within the sequence.

```sql
SELECT *
FROM (  SELECT *, DENSE_RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY [ProjectName] ORDER BY [Timestamp] DESC) AS Seq
        FROM [CMI_Industry_Workload].[dbo].[Gantt_Value]) AS T
WHERE T.Seq > 1;
```

Comment: Unless I recall incorrectly, `OFFSET` and `FETCH` don't exist in SQL Server 2008; it is, however, available in every **supported** version of SQL Server.

Comment: Ye, I just figured that out myself... not a problem :) I'll update my answer.

Comment: This works graat but only return one record, what i want is to recall all the records which are not the newest but the one before that for all the records that match TimeStamp and ProjectRef.

Comment: now i have found a way to return all the unique Timestamp for each projects, now i need to find a way to only select the prior to last record for each projets: SELECT DISTINCT Timestamp as timing , Convert(VARCHAR(MAX),ProjectRef) as Project
FROM [CMI_Industry_Workload].[dbo].[Gantt_Value]

ORDER by timing DESC

Comment: @user2073602 have updated my answer. This will generate a sequence of `1,2,3...` for each `ProjectName` based on `Timestamp` order. All you need to do then is bringing back all rows where `Seq` isn't 1.

Comment: Thanks a lot, we are nearly there, but the sequence number is not right because it count all the record of timestamp project name and not the uniques even by using a distinct such as this, so in my case i for one example need to put t = 600 to get to the second timestamp:

Comment: here is my code at the moment SELECT DISTINCT convert(varchar(MAX),[ProjectName]), [Timestamp]
FROM (  SELECT [ProjectName], [Timestamp] , ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY CONVERT(varchar(MAX), [ProjectName])  ORDER BY [Timestamp] DESC) AS Seq
        FROM [CMI_Industry_Workload].[dbo].[Gantt_Value]) AS T
WHERE T.Seq = 600 and ProjectName like 'B007E.00473';